# Unable to display AlbumArt in RemoteMediaController while casting from sender

Tags: android, chromecast, sender

I have followed this [doc](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender) to develop my cast sender app.

Unable to display album art i'm loading the media info as given below.Pleas help me out if i'm doing something wrong.

```
MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);

    mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE, "Movie");
    mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_STUDIO, "studio");
    if (null != subTitle) {
        mediaMetadata.putString("closedCaption", subTitle);
    }
    if (null != title) {
        mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, title);
    }
    if (null != mImageUrl) {
        // mediaMetadata.putString("thumb", mImageUrl);
        // mediaMetadata.putString("images", mImageUrl);
        mediaMetadata.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse(mImageUrl)));
        Boolean bImage = mediaMetadata.hasImages();
        List<WebImage> images = mediaMetadata.getImages();
        System.out.print(images.size());
    }

    MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(profileUrl).setContentType(contentType).setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED).setMetadata(mediaMetadata).build();
// And finally startcastControlleActivity 
mCastManager.startCastControllerActivity(context, mediaInfo, 0, true);
```

Comment: What receiver are you using? Does media playback starts fine? Do you see the album art in the Cast Controller Activity on your Android device? Have you looked at the console log on the Chromecast to see if there are any issues there?

Comment: The Media starts fine and plays properly.The problem is im unable to display album Art in senderApp **VideoCastControllerActivity**. The same album art is being displayed fine in notification as well lock screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally fixed the issue, Added two image uri's for metadata. Apparently videoCastControllerActiviy requires Array of WebImages and minimum of two. So that it can scale and display accordingly based on the required area(i.e Notification, LockScreen and CastControllerActivity)

```
mediaMetadata.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse(mImageUrl)));
mediaMetadata.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse(mBigImageUrl)));
```